# Decorative Solar string lights

Tags: electrical

Is it OK to attach solar string lights to an electric fence around my pasture?

The solar panel is an amorphous type, putting out 5v at 120mA. The LEDs are about 30 feet in length.

Comment: Probably if everything stays dry.  Once the rain begins all bets are off.

Comment: can you keep the solar string lights at least 6" away from the electric fence wire?  Electric fences are pretty high voltage and can induce currents in close wires.  LEDs are very energy efficient, but can be influenced by nearby circuits.   This may lead to an unwanted blinking effect as the electric fence turns on and off.

Comment: Would make working/touching the solar lights interesting.  You know it when touching an electric fence.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Elec fences are high-voltage (kilovolts) but very current-limited.  Just wanted to mention that so people don't completely freak out.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft  Thanks Carl, Good point!  Thought people knew that,  I grew up on a farm, oh well.  It's like a static shock, very high voltage, but minuscule current.

Answer (score 3):

If the **entire** setup is **completely** insulated from ground, yes, that should work. ***Until...***

The problem will be when some part of it (typically the bit with the solar panel, but any part will do) is mounted so that it's grounded, or if you mount that away from ground, comes in contact with ground (say through a horse/cow/sheep/deer/tall plant rubbing against it.)

Then you'll have low-voltage solar wiring/insulation (perpahps 50-300V insulation rating, depending what they used) between ground and 2,000-50,000 volt electric fence, the insulation will fail, the solar LED lights will fry, and that will be the end of them.

So, you should **not** attach solar lights to an electric fence.

Comment: It would make for a pretty, if brief, light show when the lights go poof!